# Constraining data over multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two columns that are unrelated but must contain similar values. For example for every row that contains `Info1=100`, each `Info2` must be the same. Also the opposite must be true, every `Info2=Broccoli` must have the same `Info1`. In the table below ID 1 and 2 would pass, ID 3,4 and 5 would fail.

```
ID Info1   Info2
---------------------
1  100      Pizza
2  100      Pizza
3  200      Carrots
4  200      Carrots
5  200      Broccoli
6  300      Broccoli
```

I am trying to create two queries, one that will show IDs that pass and one that will show IDs that fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes The correct is you normalize the data as D Stanley spoke. To identify the problems you can do as in this example:

```
declare @tab table(
    id int
    ,info1 int
    ,info2 varchar(20)
)

insert into @tab
values
    (1,  100, 'Pizza'),
    (2,  100, 'Pizza'),
    (3,  200, 'Carrots'),
    (4,  200, 'Carrots'),
    (5,  200, 'Broccoli'),
    (6,  300, 'Broccoli')

select info1, count(distinct info2) as info2distinct
from @tab t
group by info1
having count(distinct info2) > 1
```

Comment: Thanks, using count(distinct) is very useful to me here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any systems that will allow a declarative constraint like that as-is.  One solution would be to find invalid combinations with a query:

```
SELECT Info1
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT Info1, Info2
FROM table
)
GROUP BY Info1
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

and

```
SELECT Info2
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT Info1, Info2
FROM table
)
GROUP BY Info2
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

A better solution is to normalize the data:

```
ID Info1 
1  100  
2  100     
3  200     
4  200     
5  200    
6  300  

Info1   Info2
100      Pizza
200      Carrots
300      Broccoli
```

Then you can just put unique constraints on `Info1` and `Info2` to ensure that all `Info2` values have a unique `Info1`.

Comment: Thanks, I may normalize the data down the road if possible